# Bundle install: permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, bitnami, gemset

**Context**:
Trying to learn rails/ruby.
used the bitnami ubuntu ruby stack VM (2.1) as development environment. its a preinstalled VM that is detailed [here](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_RubyStack).

**Problem**:
Making a new project:
`rails new tp` 
Which will automatically run bundle install, which fails

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.8) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir=/opt/bitnami/sqlite 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling database.c
compiling backup.c
compiling sqlite3.c
compiling statement.c
compiling exception.c
linking shared-object sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so

make "DESTDIR=" install
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/sqlite3': Permission denied
make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.-.sqlite3.time] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/bitnami/.bundler/tmp/3622/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/bitnami/.bundler/tmp/3622/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Of course it fails with a permission denied because those gems are in directories managed by *root* and as the developer I create files and do my stuff as the regular *bitnami* user, of course. That includes using the rails program and using said program through an IDE.
These assumptions seem clearly at odds with how the rubystack is set up or supposed to be used.

**Questions**:
-If my methods differ from the methods assumed by the stack, then what IS the assumed method?
-If they dont differ, why is making a new project doing administration stuff?
-How should I go about making this thing work at all?

Comment: @majioa
bitnami@linux:~/rp$ ls -al /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 11:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan  3 11:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  2 12:28 NOTEMPTY

Comment: In the main post I mentioned that place was it in indeed from the  root user. The question pertaining is, should it?
/home/bitnami is NOT the location of the gems and by such this do not change anything regarding installing gems.

Comment: While rvm IS installed,     `rvm list` yields
    `# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.`
So I am supposing that the system ruby is used and using rvm will not help in any way, isnt it?

Comment: BTW running `bundle install --path ~/gems` doesn't really help. Although it DOES install (some) gems in that directory, at some point bundler will try to write again in the same directory `/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/atomic_reference.so': Permission denied`

Comment: Thanks a lot! So far I have used `sudo bundle install` but maybe that might raise permission issues later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure the:

```
ls -l /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/
```

say that the folder belongs to you, not to `root:root`.  If the rights are for [root](/questions/tagged/root) user, you can't create the folder, so to fix it just do:

```
sudo chown bitnami:bitnami /home/bitnami/. -R
```

I strongly advice you to use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) and [gemset](/questions/tagged/gemset) in order to not using the [root](/questions/tagged/root) operations. Do as follows:

1. In order to use the *system ruby* with [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) just pickup it by execution:

   ```
   rvm mount /path/to/system/ruby
   ```
2. Then create a gemset:

   ```
   rvm gemset create bitnami
   ```
3. And use it:

   ```
   rvm gemset use bitnami
   ```
4. Update or install all gems into the specified gemset, but don't use [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo) for the action, just:

   ```
   bundle install
   ```